# How to properly install StyleCop for Visual Studio 2017 Community?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, stylecop, vs-community-edition

Well i downloaded the newest version, then installed, checked to instal entire files on local drive. I restarted **Visual Studio 2017 Community** and rerun it. Unfortunatelly i can't find in menu > tools anything with should be connected with stylecop ( as in tutorial "how to use stylecop"). I am using x64 Windows7. I really really don't know how to to use it.

Answer (score 7):

Go to extensions and updates and search for stylecop in the online area.

Choose the one by Chris Dahlberg.

Close VS and it will install.

open your project up and make sure you have a settings.stylecop file in there.

right click on the project in the solution explorer and you will see a run stylecop option

Comment: You mean ...     Start VS2017.
    Go to Tools and select "Extensions and Updates..." menu.
    Select "Online" then "Visual Studio Marketplace" on the left list.
    In search box enter : "StyleCop"
    Select and download "Visual StyleCop"
    Then right click on your project and run StyleCop.

Answer (score 4):

After reading a comment from the extension creator, it appears that future development is targeted for the SytleCopAnalyzers NuGet package. Using VS 2017, this was easy to get running. Instructions here -> https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18952407)

Comment: I disagree, Karl. The essential part of the answer will change with that link. If that link is invalid, the answer is obsolete.

Comment: I would hit middle ground.  "Here is the link, you should try the link first as the material could be updated.  Here is a paste of the germane text of that link for convenience, and in case the link dies, you can use the this paste to search for future answers".   That's what I try to do.  That way, the person knows to search the links first, BUT is not screwballed if the link dies.  2-3 complete sentences is usually enough to find the new home.  and if I find the new home, I come back to SOF and add a comment about the new home.